# How do I use kivy clock to change the color of buttons?

Tags: python, kivy

I want my program to compare the time stored within the button to the current time. The button should change yellow if "early", green if "on time", and red if "late" When I run the program I get this error:

```
     honey = float(self.streak_button.id)
 AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'streak_button'
```

This is my code:

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self): # build() returns an instance
        self.store = JsonStore("streak.json") # file that stores the streaks:
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_streak, 1/30.)

        return presentation


    def check_streak(self, dt):
        honey = float(self.streak_button.id)
        #print(f"\tdelta={honey}")

        # used to give 30 minute grace period
        delay = honey + 1800
        check = False

        if honey > time.time() and honey < delay:
            check = True

        if honey > time.time():
            self.streak_button.color = 0,1,0

        if check == True:
            self.streak_button.color = 0,0,1

        if honey < time.time():
            self.streak_button.color = 1,0,0
```

```
def display_btn(self):
        # display the names of the streaks in a list on PageTwo
        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

        for value in data.values():
            if value['delta'] is not None:
                print(f"action={value['action']}, delta={value['delta']}")
                self.streak_button = StreakButton(id=str(value['delta']), text=value['action'],
                                            on_press=self.third_screen)
                self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.add_widget(self.streak_button)
```

Comment: That means that there is no attribute called streak_button as the error says.

Comment: You code is not very clear, it is normal to get that error, you never initialise the  `streak_button` attribut in  `MainApp` class.

Comment: I think, the `Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_streak, 1/30.)` and the `check_streak`  method may be defined in _screen_two_ class, and the `check_streak`  method may iterate on _streak_zone_ children to update every  `StreakButton`. I hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to change Button's colour:

- `background_normal = ''`    # To set a plain colour
- `background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]`    # Background color, in the format (r, g, b, a)

## [Kivy Button » background_color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_normal)

> ```
> background_color
> ```
>
> Background color, in the format (r, g, b, a).
>
> This acts as a multiplier to the texture colour. The default texture
>   is grey, so just setting the background color will give a darker
>   result. To set a plain color, set the [background_normal](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_normal) to ''.
>
> The [background_color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_color) is a [ListProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ListProperty) and defaults to [1,
>   1, 1, 1].

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

import time
import json


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenTwo>:
    GridLayout:
        id: streak_zone
        cols: 2
""")


class StreakButton(Button):
    # rgba = ListProperty([])

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f"\nCustomButton.on_touch_down: text={self.text}")
            self.dispatch('on_press')
            return True
        return super(StreakButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.store = JsonStore("streak.json")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_streak, 1/30.)

        return ScreenTwo()

    def check_streak(self, dt):
        print(f"\ncheck_streak:")

        # check all buttons
        for child in reversed(self.root.ids.streak_zone.children):
            honey = float(child.id)
            print(f"\tdelta={honey}")

            # used to give 30 minute grace period
            delay = honey + 1800
            check = False

            if honey > time.time() and honey < delay:
                check = True

            if honey > time.time():
                print("\t\tearly")
                child.background_normal = ''
                child.background_color = [1, 1, 0, 1]    # Yellow colour

            elif check == True:
                print("\t\ton time")
                child.background_normal = ''
                child.background_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]    # Green colour

            elif honey < time.time():
                print("\t\tlate")
                child.background_normal = ''
                child.background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]    # Red colour

    def display_btn(self):
        print(f"\ndisplay_btn:")

        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

            for value in data.values():
                if value['delta'] is not None:
                    print(f"action={value['action']}, delta={value['delta']}")
                    streak_button = StreakButton(id=str(value['delta']), text=value['action'], on_press=self.third_screen)
                    self.root.ids.streak_zone.add_widget(streak_button)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: I want the `clock.schedule_interval` to use the `check_streak` function while the `streak_button` uses a function called `third_screen` to display screen three. You have the streak button changing the color of the button, but I want the button to change when the application updates itself with the clock interval.

Comment: Do you want `check_streak` function to check all buttons or one button?

Comment: All the buttons

Comment: This solution is correct except for the fact that the `on_press` command in `display_btn()` should be `on_press = self.third_screen` because I will press the buttons to get a new screen. The `Clock.interval` will do the job that I originally had the button doing.